# patitions of the number n

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions

I'm having difficult with the following question :

A. Show that the number of partitions of n where in each one of them the even numbers appears at most once equals to the number of partitions of n in which every number appears at most three times .

Comment: The site for general mathematical questions is [math.se] not this one. This site is for questions related to current research in mathematics. Absence of mention of  such context in your post suggests the question would have been better asked there (otherwise please provide such context via an [edit]).

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake ! didnt realize that..

Comment: what's happened to 6?

Comment: it is not included, the series is 1,2,4,8,...,2^n i was wrong when i said  "which is basically the same, but u need to show it.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **A** consider the generating function;

$$\dfrac{(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^6)\dots}{(1-x)(1-x^3)(1-x^5)\dots}$$

This reads as '$0$ or $1$ of any even number, and any number of any odd numbers'.

We make progress by multiplying top and bottom by $(1+x)$ to give:

$$\dfrac{(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^6)\dots}{(1+x)(1-x)(1-x^3)(1-x^5)\dots}$$
$$=\dfrac{(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^4)(1+x^6)\dots}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^5)\dots}$$

We do the same with $(1+x^2)$:

$$\dfrac{(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^6)\dots}{(1+x^2)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^5)\dots}$$
$$=\dfrac{(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)(1+x^6)\dots}{(1-x^4)(1-x^3)(1-x^5)\dots}$$

The numerators $(1+x^k+x^{2k}+x^{3k})$ allow for $0,1,2$ or $3$ $k$'s.

We can do this trick for all the numerators using the denominators with exponent $d$ to remove all numerations with exponent $2^kd$. The denominator is left as:

$$(1-x^\infty)^\infty$$

which plays no part in the value of the coefficients of $x^k$ for finite $k$.

Comment: i didnt understand where u show that the number of the partitions are equal? where did u even talked about any of the number of the partitions ?

Comment: you could try http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function and in particular http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneratingFunction.html

Comment: @jony89; also is part B right?

Comment: if u can answer it, it will be great !

Comment: i know what is the generating function, but u said 'any number of any odd numbers' but in the question they ask for at most 3 times of each number in a particular partition. where did u relate to this part of the question ? ('at most 3 times')

Comment: also i made a lil change from : 'the even numbers appears once' to ' the even numbers appears at most once'.

Comment: @jony89; the first generating function uses at most 1 from each even number and any number from each odd. the idea is to show a bijection from this classification to that of 'any number appears at most 3 times', which is represented by my final generating function.

Comment: @jony89; and i still cant get B to work from your description of it. can you explain n=10 for me, tnx.

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: im sorry, i didnt understand the solution, how what u showed proves the question.. i understood the steps. could u just show that the generating function of the two cases are equal ?

Comment: @jony89; which bit don't you get?

Comment: i understood the math. i dont understand how your result proves the question. where did u show the equality of the number of partitions of the two cases ? mostly i didnt understand where did u show the equality to the 'any number appears at most 3 times' part..

Comment: my last GF becomes (1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9)..., with effectively no denominator, which enumerates into partitions where each part appears at most 3 times.